# Convert MemoryStream object to Outlook.MailItem

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, outlook-addin, memorystream

I am creating Outlook `add-in` in which I am creating Drag and Drop area.
I want to get mail which is drag and dropped to my control. I have used following code.:

```
    private void DragDropControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //wrap standard IDataObject in OutlookDataObject
        OutlookDataObject dataObject = new OutlookDataObject(e.Data);

        //get the names and data streams of the files dropped
        string[] filenames = (string[])dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");
        //get the Mail Item here.
        MemoryStream[] filestreams = (MemoryStream[])dataObject.GetData("FileContents");

        this.label2.Text += "Files:\n";
        for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filenames.Length; fileIndex++)
        {
            //use the fileindex to get the name and data stream
            string filename = filenames[fileIndex];
            MemoryStream filestream = filestreams[fileIndex];
            this.label2.Text += "    " + filename + "\n";

            //save the file stream using its name to the application path
            FileStream outputStream = File.Create(filename);
            filestream.WriteTo(outputStream);

            byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[outputStream.Length];

            //I don't want to save file to the local drive or something like this.
            var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\TestFileSave\\" + filename + ".msg");

            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            outputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

            fileStream.Close();

            outputStream.Close();

            readMessage(filename);
        }
    }
```

In the `readMessage(filename)` function I have get the saved file and read the `MailItem`.

But actual problem occurred when I run outlook without administrator privilege it gives me error like:

[image]

Is there any other way that without saving the file to local drive convert it to `Outlook.MailItem`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why did not read content from filestreams?

Comment: The content which I am receiving is .msg file. And I have also tried to convert it to MailItem. But it is not working.

Comment: Can your save the temp file to system temp folder?

Comment: Yes but when I run my OutLook as Administrator else it gives me error.

Comment: Can you show me the exception detail message.

Comment: @Kain I have edited the Question.. Please check...